# Flutter 3.7.12 changing Locale without reloading the application

Tags: flutter, dynamic, internationalization

I've implemented localization according to https://docs.flutter.dev/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization and I'm using a `ChangeNotifier` and `MultiProvider` to handle changes of the Locale.

I'm able to change the Locale, persist it and apply it when starting the application. The only thing that I can't get working is changing the Locale dynamically while the application is running. What happens when I change the Locale is that the application reloads / shows the root page.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!